# Combine lists of tuples by pairs into specific length of new list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am newish to Python. I'm trying to combine two lists of tuples pairwise into a single list of tuples, where the tuples are of defined length (let's say 8):

For example,

**input:**

```
x = [(0,1,2,3),(4,5,6,7),(8,9,10,11)]
y = [('a','b','c','d'),('e','f','g','h'),('i','j','k','l')]
```

**output:**

```
[('a', 0, 'b', 1, 'c', 2, 'd', 3),
 ('e', 4, 'f', 5,'g', 6, 'h', 7),
 ('i', 8, 'j', 9, 'k', 10, 'l', 11)]
```

I've tried a few different loops that attempt to concatenate the pairwise combination tuples and then add them for a given length, but no luck. See below.

```
new = []
for n in range(len(x)):
    for p in range(len(x[n])):
        if p == len(x[n])-1:
            new += [(x[n][p],y[n][p])]
            for v in range(len(x[n])):
                newer += new[v]
        else:
            new += [(x[n][p],y[n][p])]
```

The above 'newer' list is not useful, but the 'new' list provides the pairwise combination of tuples that I'm looking for, like I believe merge() would do, at least.

```
[('a', 0),('b', 1),('c', 2),('d', 3),('e', 4),('f', 5),('g', 6),('h', 7),('i', 8) ('j', 9),('k', 10), ('l', 11)]
```

I was thinking I could make a sort of window that read across the desired length (in this case four) and concatenated the selection, but have having trouble getting that to work.

Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I think the was a typo in my original post. Clearly you figured it out! Thank you for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a buffer:

```
b = [None] * 8
[tuple(b) for b[::2], b[1::2] in zip(y, x)]
```

Comment: Wow - this is beautiful. I didn’t know you could dynamically change the second variable in a list comprehension like that. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @AaronZolnai-Lucas Yeah, I'm happy every time I can use that "trick". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59889092/12671057)'s another case (though dict comprehension).

Comment: This looked very interesting at first, but now I don't like it so much because it is actually just mutating `b`, and having side effects like this in a list comprehension is not so pythonic. Just use a `for` loop instead if you want this behaviour

Comment: @jamylak We could have `b` strictly inside the list comprehension with `[tuple(b) for b in [[None] * 8] for b[::2], b[1::2] in zip(y, x)]` (doesn't even exist afterwards). I like it less, though. I think it also depends on context. Imagine those two lines being encapsulated in a function (so the function does nothing else and returns the list). Then that side effect is very local.

Comment: This is expanding my python horizon's a lot - thank you guys for this thread! Would you mind pointing me in the direction of some reading I can do to understand the dynamic change you're doing and the mutation jamylak is referring to in the list comprehension? That's the part I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: @marjorieisacat It's just slice assigments, mutating the outside variable `b`. I don't have a good tutorial or so at hand, would need to search for one, too.

Comment: Okay gotcha. I’ll figure it out :). Thanks again!

Comment: @HeapOverflow That does not look pythonic either. You should change this into a regular `for` loop or remove the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Start by zipping your sub-lists into lists of matched pairs:

```
pair_list = [list(zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(x, y) ]
```

Result:

```
[[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (4, 'd')],
 [(5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g'), (8, 'h')],
 [(9, 'i'), (10, 'j'), (11, 'k'), (12, 'l')]]
```

Now, simply flatten the inner lists.  You can look up simple flattening as an "exercise for the student", okay?

Comment: I would change the outer `list(... for a, b in ...)` into a pure list comp `[... for a, b in ...]`

Comment: @AaronZolnai-Lucas How do you conclude that?  There's nothing here that hard-codes the input length.

Comment: Exactly. You only end up with 8 because it’s a multiple of 4, which happens to be the given length. If you were asked to make 7-tuples alternating from 2 lists of 3-tuples this would not work.

Comment: That's not the problem given.  OP is asking to combine same-length lists in x and y to lists of twice the supplied length.  `len(x[i]) == len(y[i])` for all `i`.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing on my own end, something's definitely wrong with my version as it the reading frame I constructed doesn't stop at the correct length. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I ended up getting something to work:

```
final_list = []
for outer in range(len(a)):
    for ele in range(len(a[outer])):
        if ele == 0:
           slice_start = 0
        else: 
           slice_start += len(b[ele-1])
           slice_end = len(b[ele])+slice_start
           capture = [target for sublist in a[slice_start:slice_end] for target in sublist]
           final_list.append(capture)
final_list = final_list[:len(a)]
```

Definitely not as beautiful as heap_overflow's answer.